# PHP IMAP fetching mails from GMail with label doesn't fetch sent by me

Tags: php, gmail, directory, imap

I'm using PHP and IMAP to download mails from GMail with a particular label (that was automatically applied by a GMail filter). Everything is working well except that GMail is returning all the mails **except** ones sent by me. This is a problem as I need them all in order so I can process them with something else.

Here's how I'm getting it, where the label is "qv". When I view the label in GMail, all the mails are there, including my own. However, when I pull them down, my own aren't extracted.

The account I'm fetching the mails from is the same account they were sent from. When I try this exercise on a different account, where all the mails are (now) cced to, I get them all. My problem is, that account doesn't have all the mails I need to pull down, as we have only recently started copying mails to that.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

```html
// IMAP for label 
$mailbox=imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}","*******@gmail.com","XXXXXX",NULL,1,array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'PLAIN'));

$emails = imap_search($mailbox,'SUBJECT "qv" SINCE "' . $startdate . '" BEFORE "' . $enddate . '"', SE_UID);
```